# Angular 4 - Do not update ngModel for a specific option in dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel, primeng-dropdowns

I am using PrimeNG to render my dynamic dropdown options. Based on the option value I don't want my ngModel to be udpated.

Let's say if my option is an object such as dropdownObject.canUpdateModel = true, then I want my ngModel to be updated, if not ngModel should not be updated. Can someone please help me with this.

```
<p-dropdown #dp [options]="myList"(onChange)="onFMyDropdownChange(selectedForeCast)"[(ngModel)]="selectedForeCast"></p-dropdown>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use getter/setter approach, so you will be able to intercept attempt to set new value to model - inspect the value for given criteria - and assignt to model or reject the change.

It would be something like this

```
get selectedForeCast(){
   return whateverModelValue;
}

set selectedForeCast(selectedValue){
   if(selectedValue whatever here){
     whateverModelValue=selectedValue;
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Antoniossss for your reply. I have implemented as below. But if I select the option as per below else condition, first time the debugger comes to else block which is expected. But if I change the option and come back to the else conditioned option, the control is not coming to setter.

get selectedForeCast() {
    return this.selectedForecast;
  }

  set selectedForeCast(selectedForecast) {
    if (selectedForecast.status !== 'P') {
      this.selectedForecast = selectedForecast;
    } else {
      this.showGenerateScenarioStatus();
    }
  }

Comment: Maybe exception in showGenerateScenarioStatus. Cannot tell without code. Stackblitz. But anyway, this wraps up the main question here. This is the way to go.